# Issues understanding how to copy the Three.js Editor Import function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been tearing my hair out trying to understand how to implement a similar .js importer like the Three.js Editor, where a user can simply load in a .js file from the 'file load' pop-up.

I've searched Stack Exchange but either I'm missing something super obvious or the thing I'm trying to implement isn't being addressed.

I've been able to implement exporting mesh and textures from my three.js file to a 'file.js' format, but I want to be able to reload them back into a Three.js scene that is already set up to go.

Nothing I've done in the last 4 hours works and even though I've picked over the code in the editor, I can't for the life of me figure out how to import a .js file containing some basic geo and texture. The Editor imports it no worries and even shows the textures and alpha but nothing is happening for me ... :(

Comment: ...thanks for the downvote :-/ I'm new to all this coding, and considering I searched for the answer all over and had spent ages looking into how to do it, I even posted the answer if someone else needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WORKED IT OUT!!

copied and pasted the the ObjectLoader() example and then made the checked file a URL

```
function loadScene()
{
    makes.fileLoad = makes.loadScene.files[0]
    makes.fileLoadURL = URL.createObjectURL( makes.fileLoad );

    makes.hasSceneLoaded = true

    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

    loader.load(
    // resource URL
    `${makes.fileLoadURL}`,

    // onLoad callback
    // Here the loaded data is assumed to be an object
    function ( obj ) {
    // Add the loaded object to the scene
    makes.scene2.add( obj );
    },

    // onProgress callback
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
    },

    // onError callback
    function ( err ) {
        console.error( 'An error happened' );
     });
}
```